# Including dlib in Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, dlib

I am trying to add dlib library to my Qt5 project.
I've build dlib with gcc 4.9.3 using CMake without `NO_GUI_SUPPORT` (i.e. with GUI) and without `ISO_CPP_ONLY`. I've compiled it into shared library with `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX = my_qt_project_dir/dlib`, installed and included it into my project:

```
# DLIB
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/dlib/include/
LIBS += -L$$PWD/dlib/lib/
LIBS += -ldlib
```

I am including this headers in code:

```
#include <dlib/image_processing.h>
#include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>
#include <dlib/image_io.h>
#include <dlib/dir_nav.h>
#include <dlib/opencv.h>
```

but during compilation get [this errors](http://pastebin.com/Td6LvmQV)

some of them:

```
/dlib/include/dlib/image_processing/../matrix/matrix_la.h:64:45: error: macro "sign" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
/dlib/include/dlib/image_processing/../matrix/matrix_math_functions.h:83:27: error: expected unqualified-id before 'const'
/dlib/include/dlib/image_processing/../matrix/matrix_la.h:1034:9: error: 'matrix' has not been declared
```

I am using CMake 3.3.1, QtCreator 3.4.2, Qt 5.4.2, gcc 4.9.3 running on gentoo 4.0.9.

How to deal with this?

Comment: Someone #defined the word "sign" and it's stomping on the code.  Figure out what code creates the sign #define and #include it after other headers.

Comment: @DavisKing I have searched through c++ symbols with QtCreator and found only this 3 definitions related to project:

1) `namespace dlib` -> `namespace impl` -> `inline type sign (const type& val)`

2) `namespace dlib` -> `namespace nric` -> `inline T sign(const T& a, const T& b)`

3) `DLIB_DEFINE_FUNCTION_M(op_sign, sign, impl::sign, 6);`
These definitions are always under namespaces so there should not be a problem with them. More like compiler can't decide what definition to use. I've tried to specify namespaces in calls, but without any result...

Comment: The #define isn't in the dlib code.

Comment: @DavisKing looks like you are right. I have copy-pasted this code to new project and it has built. But I can't find any other `sign` definition. Still investigating...

Comment: @DavisKing ok, I've got this. Other 3d party lib included to my project indeed had a `#define sign`. Strange that I wasn't able to find it with QtCreator search via text

Comment: @DavisKing you can add your comment about `#define` as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone #defined the word "sign" and it's stomping on the code. Figure out what code creates the sign #define and #include it after other headers.